# Extracting values from javascript inserted html table to calculate something

Tags: javascript, html, excel

So I am trying to make a web tool that can calculate commission for a sales team, I have an Excel sheet I can extract to see all the deals that are eligible for commission.
To this point I can put the excel sheet values into a HTML table but i want to do calculations with these values.

So my question is: is there a way I can extract/use the values from the table and do some calculations with it?

Code:

```html
<input type="file" id="fileUpload" />
    <input type="button" id="upload" value="Upload" onclick="Upload()" />
    <hr />
    <div id="dvExcel"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.13.5/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.13.5/jszip.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Upload() {
            //Reference the FileUpload element.
            var fileUpload = document.getElementById("fileUpload");
    
            //Validate whether File is valid Excel file.
            var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.xls|.xlsx)$/;
            if (regex.test(fileUpload.value.toLowerCase())) {
                if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
    
                    //For Browsers other than IE.
                    if (reader.readAsBinaryString) {
                        reader.onload = function (e) {
                            ProcessExcel(e.target.result);
                        };
                        reader.readAsBinaryString(fileUpload.files[0]);
                    } else {
                        //For IE Browser.
                        reader.onload = function (e) {
                            var data = "";
                            var bytes = new Uint8Array(e.target.result);
                            for (var i = 0; i < bytes.byteLength; i++) {
                                data += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
                            }
                            ProcessExcel(data);
                        };
                        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileUpload.files[0]);
                    }
                } else {
                    alert("This browser does not support HTML5.");
                }
            } else {
                alert("Please upload a valid Excel file.");
            }
        };
        function ProcessExcel(data) {
            //Read the Excel File data.
            var workbook = XLSX.read(data, {
                type: 'binary'
            });
    
            //Fetch the name of First Sheet.
            var firstSheet = workbook.SheetNames[0];
    
            //Read all rows from First Sheet into an JSON array.
            var excelRows = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workbook.Sheets[firstSheet]);
    
            //Create a HTML Table element.
            var table = document.createElement("table");
            table.border = "4";
    
            //Add the header row.
            var row = table.insertRow(-1);
    
            //Add the header cells.
            var headerCell = document.createElement("TH");
            headerCell.innerHTML = "Rep";
            row.appendChild(headerCell);
    
            headerCell = document.createElement("TH");
            headerCell.innerHTML = "Type";
            row.appendChild(headerCell);
    
            headerCell = document.createElement("TH");
            headerCell.innerHTML = "Number";
            row.appendChild(headerCell);
    
            headerCell = document.createElement("TH");
            headerCell.innerHTML = "Client";
            row.appendChild(headerCell);
    
            headerCell = document.createElement("TH");
            headerCell.innerHTML = "Revenue";
            row.appendChild(headerCell);
    
            headerCell = document.createElement("TH");
            headerCell.innerHTML = "Equipment";
            row.appendChild(headerCell);
    
            headerCell = document.createElement("TH");
            headerCell.innerHTML = "Share";
            row.appendChild(headerCell);
    
            headerCell = document.createElement("TH");
            headerCell.innerHTML = "Other";
            row.appendChild(headerCell);
    
            headerCell = document.createElement("TH");
            headerCell.innerHTML = "Date";
            row.appendChild(headerCell);
    
            headerCell = document.createElement("TH");
            headerCell.innerHTML = "Paidinfulldate";
            row.appendChild(headerCell);
    
    
            //Add the data rows from Excel file.
            for (var i = 0; i < excelRows.length; i++) {
                //Add the data row.
                var row = table.insertRow(-1);
                var client = "Client/Vendor"
    
                //Add the data cells.
                var cell = row.insertCell(-1);
                cell.innerHTML = excelRows[i].Rep;
    
                cell = row.insertCell(-1);
                cell.innerHTML = excelRows[i].Type;
    
                cell = row.insertCell(-1);
                cell.innerHTML = excelRows[i].Number;
    
                cell = row.insertCell(-1);
                cell.innerHTML = excelRows[i].Client;
    
                cell = row.insertCell(-1);
                cell.innerHTML = excelRows[i].Revenue;
    
                cell = row.insertCell(-1);
                cell.innerHTML = excelRows[i].Equipment;
    
                cell = row.insertCell(-1);
                cell.innerHTML = excelRows[i].Share;
    
                cell = row.insertCell(-1);
                cell.innerHTML = excelRows[i].Other;
    
                cell = row.insertCell(-1);
                cell.innerHTML = excelRows[i].Date;
    
                cell = row.insertCell(-1);
                cell.innerHTML = excelRows[i].Paidinfulldate;
    
            }
    
            var dvExcel = document.getElementById("dvExcel");
            dvExcel.innerHTML = "";
            dvExcel.appendChild(table);
        };
    </script>
```

Comment: You may be better off populating an array with the data that is coming from Excel just prior to putting it into your table, then you can just get it from the array. Otherwise, you'll just have to access the table cells and get the `.textContent` of those cells. And, by the way use `.textContent` to populate the table cells, not `innerHTML`, which has security and performance implications.

Comment: But how do I access these table cells?

Comment: There are many different ways to access element within a document (`document.getElementById()`, `document.querySelector()`, `document.querySelectorAll()`, an [`HTMLTableCellElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableCellElement), to name a few.